# Out Of Bounds Exception, when trying to print array

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I have this problem, been stuck for hours now.

This method is getting out of bounds exception when i try to print it.
Im using the input variables from the method posted below this. Thanks!

```
public static double [] calcLine(double x, double k, double m){
    double tx = 1;
    double[] list = new double[(int) x]; 
    for(double i =1; i <= 5; i++){

        list[(int) i]+= calcPoint(tx,k,m);
        tx++;
    }

        return list;

}
```

This is the calcPoint method i use;

```
public static double calcPoint(double x,double k, double m){

    double calcPointInput = k*x+m;
    return calcPointInput;
}
```

Cheers L

Comment: `for(double i =1; i <= 5; i++)` ... hmmm ... `list[(int) i]`. Look at this again.

Comment: Hint : When you have array size of `n` , then the array indexes start from `0` to `n-1`. There is no index `n` in it.

Comment: @Keerthivasan, thank you for the comment. How do i fix it?

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for making me aware of the duplicate question. I read it. But im still not able no solve the exception. Thanks!

Comment: Change to `for(int i =0; i < list.length; i++){list[i]+= calcPoint(tx,k,m);}`

Comment: @Keerthivasan thanks! I sloved it like this  `public static double[] calcLine(double x, double k, double m){
  double tx = 0;
  double[] list = new double[10]; 
  for(int i =0; i <= x; i++){
   
   list[i]+= calcPoint(tx,k,m);
  tx++;
  }
 
   return list;
   
}`